# Local Positioning System ( LPS ) as opposed to GPS?

Tags: gps, ip

I have a bunch of computers in an area and I want to know positions of those computer. The place is wified so only thing through which they can be distinguished is by the IP address. Output would be coordinate of the computer given its IP address in context to the pre-defined origin.

So, this is kind of LPS (Local) as opposed to GPS.

I am seeing if Sun Spot can be used, but I have no idea how this can be accomplished.Any directions would be appreciated.

Thanks
Karan

Comment: Are the computers fixed or mobile (i.e. laptops)? Would it be enough to just know in which WiFi cell the computer is in?

Comment: Laptops shall be confined to the cafe wifi area, hence they belong to the same cell as that defined by Cafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the access points (AP) BSSID (that is the MAC address) for tracking. If you don't have the data available, you can collect the data with [Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/). Then you can create a table that maps AP addresses to rooms.

If you have GPS reception in your rooms (for example if they have windows and are not in the inner of the building), you can also connect Kismet with gpsd to connect GPS coordinates with location. Yes, this is a 3D coordinate, if your GPS unit supports height data. Here is an example output:

```
    <gps-point bssid="00:2F:F6:40:3C:C4" source="00:2F:6f:40:3C:C4" 
     time-sec="1314046060" time-usec="483219" 
     lat="23.144650" lon="78.417402" spd="0.000000" heading="179.680801" 
     fix="3" alt="541.559021"
     signal_dbm="-26" noise_dbm="0"/>
```

For details on how to set up your GPS, see the documentation on [Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/) homepage.

Comment: Shall it give me 3-D cordinates of a machine?